# JDK for Eclipse(in windows platform)

Tags: java, eclipse

My qustion is really simple, all in the title.

After some tests I found that by given a JRE/bin directory in the `path`(environment variable) , Eclipse can run normally with no problem. And Eclipse will never try to find the `JRE` by using `JAVA_HOME` variable.

And in eclipse, I know that I can add `installed JREs` in the window preference and choose a `JDK` folder instead of a `JRE` folder. And for each project, we can change the compiler level.

Since Eclipse can also compile the codes, when is JDK used? Debug? or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse uses its own compiler to compile Java code. It is different than the javac compiler that comes with a JDK. In fact, you don't need a JDK to compile and run normal Java projects in Eclipse. A JRE is obviously needed to reference the required Java libraries.

However if you are using Maven or some other tools that sometimes depend on a JDK component, then you need to install a JDK on your machine. For example, Maven has an option to rely on the tools.jar that comes shipped with a JDK.

Comment: You mean even using Maven or Ant as plugins in Eclipse? Or run Maven/Ant from CMD?

Comment: well, I tested ANT, it's based on the JAVA_HOME, any other situations?

Comment: I know of Maven and Ant that require a JDK (regardless of whether used as plugins in Eclipse or from command line)

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse uses the `JRE` you specified as default or per project settings. This could be a (only) JRE installation or a JRE from a JDK installation.

I think the more interesting question is: When should I use a JDK instead of an JRE?

The JDK includes tool that are not included in the standalone JRE. E.g. the `javadoc.exe` for exporting the documentation from javadoc annotated comments in the code. This Program is not included in a standalone JRE. so if you want to export your javadoc documentation you need to add an installed JRE based on a JDK installation first, so Eclipse is able to use the javadoc tool.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a little hard to give a thorough answer to this but I know that at least for using Maven/m2e Eclipse needs to be run in a JDK.

Answer (score -1):

First of all eclipse is a java code it wouldn't run without java installed to prove it (on your personal expence) copy the eclipse folder elsewhere and uninstal the JDK and try to run jave it wouldn't it would output the error message no JDK but instal JDK and run eclipse from the copied location it would run as a first time asking you about the workplace directory!.